# POST method not allowed when calling flask API. exact error: POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, flask, post

I am creating a grade prediction app where I have a React form frontend and a Flask API where I send data to the api and it returns me a grade after predicting it with a random forest classifier. I have never created a flask api before and I cant find an answer to this. Here is my flask api code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
import joblib
import numpy as np
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

classifier = joblib.load("random_forest_grade.joblib")

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET']) 
def home():
    return "Hello world"

@app.route("/grades", methods=['POST', "GET"])
def grades():
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            formData = request
            data = [val for val in formData.values()]
            prediction = classifier.predict(np.array(data).reshape(1, -1))
            types = {0:"A",1:"B",2:"C",3:"D",4:"F"}
            response = jsonify({
            "statusCode": 200,
            "status": "Prediction made",
            "result": types[prediction[0]]
            })
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            return response
        except Exception as error:
            return jsonify({
                "statusCode": 500,
                "status": "Could not make prediction",
                "error": str(error)
            })

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my React function which calls the flask api

```
    submitForm = () =>{
    const {formData,step, isLoading, result} = this.state
    this.setState({isLoading:true, step: step+1})
    const newCurrent = Math.ceil(formData.current/5)-3
    
    this.setState({formData: {...formData, current: newCurrent}})
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', formData)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        result: response.result,
        isLoading: false
      });
    }).catch(err =>{
        this.setState({
            result: "Does not work",
            isLoading: false
          });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must fix the URL, from http://127.0.0.1:5000/ to http://127.0.0.1:5000/grades